# MySQL - Yesterday, Week-To-Date, Year-To-Date Aggregation?

Tags: mysql

I have this dataset:

```
+---------+----------+-------+-------+
| Date    | Salesman | Calls | Sales |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+
| 3/15/21 | Bob      | 5     | 2     |
| 3/15/21 | Jim      | 4     | 2     |
| 3/15/21 | Frank    | 3     | 1     |
| 3/16/21 | Bob      | 6     | 3     |
| 3/16/21 | Jim      | 7     | 4     |
| 3/16/21 | Frank    | 3     | 2     |
| 3/17/21 | Bob      | 4     | 5     |
| 3/17/21 | Jim      | 3     | 2     |
| 3/17/21 | Frank    | 2     | 1     |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to output each salesman's results on a daily basis for yesterday, week-to-date and even year-to-date in this fashion:

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Salesman | Yesterday Success | WTD Success | YTD Success |
+----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Bob      | 80.00%            | 66.67%      | 66.67%      |
| Jim      | 66.00%            | 57.14%      | 57.14%      |
| Frank    | 50.00%            | 50.00%      | 50.00%      |
+----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

My current code is:

```
SELECT Salesman
     , SUM(Calls) AS Calls
     , SUM(Sales) as Sales
     , SUM(Calls) / SUM(Sales) as Success
  FROM Database
 WHERE Date = CURDATE()-1
 GROUP 
    BY Salesman
```

Which approach should I take to add the WTD / YTD columns beside Yesterday's?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Which approach should I take - conditional aggregation

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon